# How to ignore comment while streaming stream through a file

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I'm trying to iterate through a sql file using java stream and in that file I want to ignore the comments in the sql file.

I could handle the comments written in one line
For Ex: /* Hello World */

```
if ((line.trim().startsWith("/*") & line.trim().endsWith("*/")) ) {
                        return;
                    }
```

But how to handle comments which are written in multiple lines like

/*
Hello

World

*/

What could be written inside the do while loop?

```
if (line.trim().startsWith("/*")){
                        do {
                            //How to iterate through the stream here to find the ending of the comment.
                                }
                      while ( ! line.trim().endsWith("*/"));
```

Comment: I want to execute all the sql's line by line written inside the files using this.jdbc.executeQuery(line); and ignore the comments written inside the file.

Comment: Why do you need to ignore the comments? They won't be executed anyway.

Comment: @Unmitigated To see the proper logs and output of the select queries without getting syntax errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the liberty to read the file as a `String` then you can use regex to filter out the commented lines:

```java
String linesWithoutComments = data.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.+?\\*/", "");
```

Test data:

```
/* Hello

World

*/

This is line 1

This is line 2

/* Some comment */

This is line 3
```

Output:

```
This is line 1

This is line 2



This is line 3
```